# ORA-01008: not all variables bound - VB.NET web application

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am writing a VB.NET function to update a table with four columns as per below. It is failing every time with the exception  **ORA-01008: not all variables bound**

Can someone please help?

```
Public Sub UpdateLog(ByVal intUserID As Integer, ByVal strDesc As String, ByVal intLogID As Integer)

Dim oraConn As OracleConnection

    Dim cmd As OracleCommand

    Try
        cmd = New OracleCommand
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Tbl_Trans_Log(UserID,TransID,TransDate,ActionDone) values (:userId,:logId,:transdate,:action)"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.BindByName = True

        cmd.Parameters.Add("userId", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = intUserID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("logId", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = intLogID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("transdate", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now
        cmd.Parameters.Add("action", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = strDesc

        oraConn = New OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connString").ConnectionString)
        oraConn.Open()

        cmd.Connection = oraConn
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



    Catch ex As Exception
        sWriteErrorLog("C:\", "log - sUpdateTransLog -> " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        oraConn.close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: it seems the rows should be ended up with semi-colons, and `" & ex.Message` ,in the exception part, should be quoted as `" & ex.Message"`

Comment: Hi Barbaros, Thanks for you reply.

Should i give the statement like this? with semicolon

cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Tbl_Trans_Log(UserID,TransID,TransDate,ActionDone) values (:userId,:logId,:transdate,:action);"

Comment: If you're using BindByName I think you may need to make sure your oracle-variables names match, have you tried adding `:`?

Comment: as much as i know you don't need a semi-colon inside of quotation, but   as i know should exist after quotes like `...values (:userId,:logId,:transdate,:action)";`

Comment: Hi soohiinigan, Yes i have tried adding : to the paramaters. It is still the same result

Comment: the semicolon will not work 
inside the quotation - Exception->SQL command not properly ended.
outside quotation-> syntax error. no semis allowed in vb.net

Comment: Do you get ORA-01008, when you remove the parts related to `transdate` such as `cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Tbl_Trans_Log(UserID,TransID,ActionDone) values (:userId,:logId,:action)` and getting rid of the row `cmd.Parameters.Add("transdate", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now`?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. I got the solution. Posting it soon

Comment: I have one last doubt. Will this work?

cmd.CommandText = "Update Tbl_Active_User set LoginDate=sysdate where Username=:username"

Or should i add a parameter containing sysdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me.

cmd = New OracleCommand

```
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Tbl_Trans_Log(UserID,TransID,TransDate,ActionDone) values (:userId,:logId,:transdate,:action)"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.BindByName = True

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":userId", OracleDbType.Int64)).Value = intUserID
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":logId", OracleDbType.Int64)).Value = intLogID
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":transdate", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = DateTime.Now
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter(":action", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = strDesc

        oraConn = New OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xxxxxxxxx").ConnectionString)
        oraConn.Open()

        cmd.Connection = oraConn
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```